# Possible to shoot bullets (PictureBoxes) without using space (like in Space Invaders), for example using a timer?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I'm creating an Arcadium type game (Space Invaders, but you dont press space to shoot) and im having difficulty making my ship shoot bullets on a timer.

I managed to make the ship move without any trouble, but I can only find how to shoot using space bar, not using a set interval of time (ex. shooting every 10 ms).

Do I use an array of PictureBoxes of the same Bullet PictureBox and an index to keep shooting them (lazy variant, inefficient)? Or is there a way to permanently generate PictureBoxes?

Comment: I'm afraid using a `PictureBox` for every bullet is going to make your game extremely slow - a better alternative within the WinForms domain would be to use the `Paint` event.

Comment: Use the right tool for the job. WinForms is not a good platform for making games.

Comment: Its just a casual application for a certificate we have to get (it's like a school project, doesn't need to be awfully efficient) (i'm still in high school). Also, I don't have time to spare to learn a new engine as I'm practicing for my exams.